# Could plankton create civilisation?

Tags: society, technology, civilization, underwater, sea-creatures

Could a species of planktonic beings, with sufficient intelligence, creativity, and physical ability to manipulate objects, create a technological civilisation at the same level as humans? While being unable to control their motion is a massive detriment, it seems plausible that they might find a way to work with or even overcome the currents through technology. Please ignore any issues that apply to aquatic beings as a whole

Comment: the first problem is plankton with sufficient intelligence is biologically impossible as we know it.

Comment: @John Why? There are definitely plankters (or similar-enough species at least) that could easily get enough energy to support a human-power brain

Comment: "Enough energy for a brain" is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: there is not enough room for enough neurons for intelligence. if you are just going ot handwave that they their capabilities is entirely up to you.

Comment: @John Some plankters are literally wider than a man is tall. The space is there

Comment: only if you stretch the definition of plankton to the point it is meaningless, at that point just say fish that are poor swimmers. there is a difference between unable to control their motion, and behaviorally rarely doing so. speaking of which you need to define the shape and capabilities of your creature before this can be answered.

Comment: @John Something is a part of the plankton if it can't swim against current. This definition (which is the one that wikipedia and many other sources use) can fit any species at any size

Comment: Is this question asking for permission to create a telekinetic species? Or a telepathic species that controls others? Else how can they create any technology at all?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. They could have hands or some other sort of manipulator

Comment: "Could have"? Can you please add important details such as this to the question.

Comment: The way you've edited the question it makes it seem as if they have some kind of internal factory - is that what you mean? Do you mean instead "manipulate objects", can you also indicate the degree of dexterity and manipulation and the scale it occurs on - microscopic, macroscopic etc?

Comment: Per the [help/dont-ask], "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question [and/or] there is no actual problem to be solved." So, VTC: not about WB according to the rules. By definition, it's your world, and if your plankton have achieved human sapience, then they have the ability to develop a civilization. So, what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Could you specify what kind of [plankton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plankton) you're interested in and where along its evolutionary path you're focusing. That definition of "plankton" is way too broad to be usefull.

Comment: To put it in a nutshell:  if a question calls for enough creativity or is important enough to be worth answering, it will be closed.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact The problem I'm trying to solve is if plankton could realistically make a technological civilization, with respect to the fact that they are planktonic, and so are highly restrained in how they can move. I don't see why that's so obscure

Comment: @IchthysKing That's not a problem to solve - you've already declared as a rule of your world that they area as sapient, as intelligent, as humanity. That's only achievable if civilizations were created. This Stack doesn't deal with issues of philosophy, only with specific issues during the process of building a world. Remember from the [help/on-topic], "must be specific and answerable."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could a species of planktonic beings, with sufficient intelligence and creativity... While being unable to control their motion is a massive detriment

No, no, no, no, no. Nope. How did they develop "intelligence and creativity" if they cannot even control their motion?

While it is true that form follows function, the lack of a form will disable any potential function.

Case at point - humans inherited opposable thumb from arboreal primates. It enabled them lately to used tools and thus contributed to the development of intelligence. Intelligence needed the frequent use of tools but didn't "create" opposable thumbs as a way to emerge.

Answer (score 5):

### Absolutely not.

Increased intelligence isn't something that magically appears in a species; it has to be selected for... and physically possible.

First of all, a sapient brain is necessarily bigger than a plankton's body. It takes a minimum amount of physical hardware to compute anything.

Second, if plankton can't even control their movement, they don't benefit from increased intelligence, so there's no pressure to increase intelligence. In fact, for a planktonic being, increased intelligence would be a detriment, since it requires a higher caloric intake and (in this case) provides no benefit whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

### If they can link together to accomplish complex tasks then maybe.

Taking ants for reference they can't accomplish much on their own but are an unstoppable force in great numbers. They don't have a civilisation per se but they can build large nests, wage wars between colonies, farm mushrooms and herd aphids. They do this thanks to two things: mandibles to manipulate their environment and pheromones to communicate among themselves. We for example have hands and can talk. Grab and communicate, it's a useful rule of thought when designing a civilisation capable species.

If the zooplankton could link up with each other they could form large schools(?) and grab and manipulate objects. The way they communicate could be anything. Light, scent or sound.

However intelligence is the limiting factor. Multiple tiny brains working together aren't as good as one large brain. Ants can do intelligent decisions but that's because their pheromones are a type of external memory. Each ant only follows basic rules. That's why we still dominate (for now).

Answer (score 1):

### They're smarter than you think...

[image]
Single dinoflagellate cells (plankton) [actually produce an eye with a lens and retina](http://www.sci-news.com/biology/science-warnowiid-dinoflagellate-plankton-eyes-02973.html).  Having a retina is a good hint that they may keep mental track of the positions of objects, though I haven't seen much work on this.

Now you may wonder what a single cell can do without a brain.  But remember, cells have many thousands of different regulatory genes, each of which produces a protein can affect others in a complicated network - a *neural* network, you might say.  With a sufficiently complex protein network, you could have quite a bit of processing power.

What about fire?  Well, who needs it?  The point of fire is to transform substances - ore to metal, dead chicken to barbecue.  If the cells actually did have a sufficiently complex neural network, they could make new protein sequence on the fly to provide surfaces with any desired pattern of catalytic activity - accomplishing all the purposes of fire, and much more, without ever needing such absurdly high activation energies.

Now does this seem far fetched?  Of course ... we're writing sci-fi here.  You would face equal skepticism if you interviewed a corporation in the future and tried to convince it that the ordinary worker unit, that it had just printed in a sessile cube chassis with specialized software preinstalled and slotted into a rack in a server complex, was actually the descendant of a free-living and "sentient" species that had existed just a few hundred years previously.